# Variadic templates type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I came across this great article: http://pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html

In the following code :

```
template<class A, template<class...> class B> struct mp_rename_impl;

template<template<class...> class C, class... T, template<class...> class B>
struct mp_rename_impl<C<T...>, B>
{
    using type = B<T...>;
};

template<class A, template<class...> class B>
using mp_rename = typename mp_rename_impl<A, B>::type;

//...
mp_rename<mp_list<int, float, void*>, std::tuple>; // -> std::tuple<int, float, void*>
                                                   // T... will be deduced as int, float, void*
```

Why **C** is deduced as **mp_list** (instead of **mp_list< int, float, void* >**) and **T...** as **int, float, void*** ?

I think the trick is the template specialization part :
**struct mp_rename_impl< C < T... >, B>**, But I struggle to understand why

Comment: Which `A` ? `class A` or `template<class...> class A` ?

Comment: I renamed to C as you did to make it clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with

```
mp_rename<mp_list<int, float, void*>, std::tuple>;
```

- in

  ```
  template<class A, template<class...> class B>
  using mp_rename = typename mp_rename_impl<A, B>::type;
  ```

  `A` is `mp_list<int, float, void*>` and `B` is `std::tuple`
- in

  ```
   template<class A, template<class...> class B> struct mp_rename_impl;
  ```

  `A` is `mp_list<int, float, void*>` and `B` is `std::tuple` in the same way.
- in the specialization

  ```
  template<template<class...> class C, class... Ts, template<class...> class B>
  struct mp_rename_impl<C<Ts...>, B>
  ```

  (I rename to `C` to be clearer)
  `C` is `mp_list`, `Ts...` is `int, float, void*` and `B` is `std::tuple`.

Comment: It took me a while to get it for some reason, but I was wondering how could we split `mp_list< Ts... >` to `mp_list` and `Ts...`. But `struct mp_rename_impl< C< Ts... >, B >` specialize `template< class A, template< class...> class B > struct mp_rename_impl;`, which is a better match if `A` -> `mp_list< int, float, void* >`. The specialization `struct mp_rename_impl< C< Ts... >, B >`  allow us to separate `C` and `Ts...`